# Can I display volume or brightness popup using command?

Tags: brightness, notification, volume-control

When you adjust your brightness or volume in ubuntu, you would see a popup notification in the top right corner of the screen to notify you the level of brightness or volume. Just as follows:

[image: volume popup]

I can adjust the volume with the command `amixer -D pulse sset Master 10%+`, but I don't know the volume level after executing the command each time. So I thought maybe I could add a command to display the volume popup. Is there a command that is able to do the trick?